# YouTube video background not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I want to put the video from YouTube in the background of the site but the title of video is not hiding. I don't know why, because I put in the URL "controls=0". Here's the code and screen.
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddjzD.jpg)
Code:

```
<div class="video-background">
        <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NwbEe6-EYFA?&theme=dark&autoplay=1&keyboard=1&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&start=14&controls=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.video-background {
position: fixed; 
z-index: -99; 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? it think this code is working fine because "showinfo=0" work for hide title of youtube video.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: I tried your code with Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome and no title for me, strange. Maybe it depends on the version.

Comment: you could convert the video to an mp4, then everything should work fine.